# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, json

I have the following code to load JSON:

```
import json
import requests
r = requests.get('http://api.reddit.com/controversial?limit=5')
if r.status_code = 200:
    reddit_data = json.loads(r.content)
    print reddit_data['data']['children'][1]['data']
else:
    print "Errror."
```

And I got this message.

```
arsh@arsh:~$ python q.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "q.py", line 1, in <module>
    import json
  File "/home/arsh/json.py", line 5, in <module>
    reddit_data = json.loads(r.content)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'loads'
```

Comment: is  it a `get` error or a `loads` error?

Comment: @MartijnPieters, there are two different errors in the question. get would mean requests

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: ah, yes, the question title doesn't even match the traceback posted. Tsk, tsk.

Answer (score 2):

You have a **different** file called `json.py` in your home directory:

```
File "/home/arsh/json.py", line 5, in <module>
```

This file is in the way, you did not import the standard library version. Rename it to something else or delete it. You'll also have to remove the `json.pyc` file.

Note that `requests` response objects can already handle JSON responses *for you*:

```
import requests

r = requests.get('http://api.reddit.com/controversial?limit=5')
r.raise_for_status()
reddit_data = r.json()
print reddit_data['data']['children'][1]['data']
```

The [`Response.json()` method](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.json) handles decoding JSON for you, including detecting the correct characterset to use when decoding.